I want to build a ultra low latency live streaming application using raspberry pi, picamera and ffmpeg
I’m working on building an ultra-low-latency live streaming application using the Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2. My setup includes FFmpeg for video streaming over UDP to achieve low latency, and FFmpeg with SRT for reliable recording. The SRT protocol helps prevent packet loss during recording, maintaining consistent quality by adjusting based on network capabilities.
I’ve also developed a basic HTML, CSS, and JavaScript interface to view the live stream, control start and stop for both streaming and recording, and stream directly to platforms like YouTube and Twitch. For real-time adjustments to bitrate, resolution, and FPS during streaming and recording, I’m planning to use Picamera2 with WebSockets, and Flask to handle the backend.
The main goal of this project is to achieve ultra-low latency for live streaming while also ensuring reliable recording. If you have any ideas for improvement or feedback on the setup, it would be much appreciated. Let me know if there are ways to refine the implementation!

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

how is this specific to the Raspberry Pi?
